# Jpa hibernate merge error

Tags: java, web-service, jpa, crud

## Erro

> Hibernate: select SEQ_COUNT from SEQUENCE_TABLE where SEQ_NAME = 'EMP_SEQ' for update
>   Hibernate: update SEQUENCE_TABLE set SEQ_COUNT = ? where SEQ_COUNT = ? and SEQ_NAME = 'EMP_SEQ'
>   Hibernate: insert into contatos (email, nome, id) values (?, ?, ?)
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
>   INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
>   WARN: SQL Warning Code: 1364, SQLState: HY000
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
>   WARN: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
>   WARN: SQL Warning Code: 1364, SQLState: HY000
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
>   WARN: Field 'updated_at' doesn't have a default value
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
>       at br.com.contatoapi1.contato.dao.ContatoJpaDAO.saveOrUpdate(ContatoJpaDAO.java:42)
>       at br.com.contatoapi1.contato.controller.ContatoApiController.findAll(ContatoApiController.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
>       ... 40 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>       ... 40 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>       ... 53 more
>   jul 15, 2016 3:13:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springrest] in context with path [/contato] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:105)
>       at br.com.contatoapi1.contato.dao.ContatoJpaDAO.saveOrUpdate(ContatoJpaDAO.java:47)
>       at br.com.contatoapi1.contato.controller.ContatoApiController.findAll(ContatoApiController.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

## Model

Obs: `@Entity @Table(name = "contatos")` estão em cima da declaração da classe.

```
public class Contato {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN", table="SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME",
    valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue="EMP_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

## DAO

```
public class ContatoJpaDAO {

    private final EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private Contato contato;

    public ContatoJpaDAO() {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("contato");
        this.entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(Contato contato) {
        try {

            this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            this.entityManager.merge(contato);
            this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            this.entityManager.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class ContatoApiController {
    Contato contato;
    private final ContatoJpaDAO contatoJpaDAO = new ContatoJpaDAO();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/contato", headers="Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    private void findAll(@RequestBody Contato contato) {
         contatoJpaDAO.saveOrUpdate(contato);
    }
}
```

Comment: É possivel removeres partes da pergunta que não interessam ao problema? Como está tem coisas a mais, dificil ter tempo para ler tudo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá até vergonha de dizer hehehe mas foi o seguinte:

eu estava estudando RubyOnRails e usei o banco criado por ele eu lembrei que o rails cria 2 campos a mais `update_at` e o `created_ad` entao eu nao estava colocando nem um valor para eles hehe :) foi so eu trocar de banco que funcionou. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Cara acredito que no seu metodo de saveOrUpdate faltou algo como testar para ver se o contato já existe, para fazer o merge, pois o merge é para algo ja que esta no banco. Caso não exista deve ser usado o persist segue o código refatorado testar ai e qualquer coisa posta nos comentarios!

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Contato contato) {
try {

    this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    if(contato.getId != null)//teste para ver se de fato existe o id se existe merge senão persist
    {
        this.entityManager.merge(contato);
    }
    this.entityManager.persist(cliente);
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    this.entityManager.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    this.entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}
}
```

Comment: Opa muito obrigado por ter respondido coloquei seu codigo mas nao funcionou deu o mesmo erro, o merge se nao me engano ele faz a busca caso exista ele atualiza se nao existir ele cria um novo num e isso?